# When button is pressed, the command doesn't run

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
def setAlarm():
    X = 5+5
    frame2.tkraise()
    print X

app = Tk()

hour = IntVar()
minute = IntVar()
period = StringVar()
hour.set(None)
minute.set(None)
period.set(None)
frame1 = Frame(app) #main frame
frame2 = Frame(app) #hour frame
frame3 = Frame(app) #minutes frame
frame4 = Frame(app) #period frame
frame5 = Frame(app) #something frame
    for frame in (frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, frame5):
        frame.grid(row=10, column=10, sticky='news') # sets frame layout

setAlarm = Button(frame1, text = "Set Alarm", command = lambda:setAlarm()).pack()
```

I have a button in frame 1, that when pressed it supposed to show frame 2. However when I click the button, nothing happens. Shouldn't setAlarm() be called which brings frame2 to the front? Instead I get this error.

```
File "C:/Users/Jeffrey/PycharmProjects/untitled/Graphical User 
Interface.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    setAlarm = Button(frame1, text = "Set Alarm", command = 
lambda:setAlarm()).pack()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You define the `setAlarm` function but then overwrite it as soon as this line executes

`setAlarm = Button(frame1, text = "Set Alarm", command = lambda:setAlarm()).pack()`

with `None` (`pack()` returns `None`) .

You don't need this reassignment to `setAlarm`.

As a matter of fact you don't even need the `lambda`. You already defined `setAlarm` so you might as well use it directly:

`Button(frame1, text="Set Alarm", command=setAlarm).pack()`

**Further explanation**

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
def foo():
    print('foo')

bar = lambda: foo()

foo = None

bar()
```

Which results with the same error:

```
bar = lambda: foo()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

By the time `bar()` executes, `foo` is already `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `lambda` in the `command` for `setAlarm` button.

`command = setAlarm` must not call the function (remove the parenthesis).

That button does not need to be named, and surely not shadowing the `setAlarm` function. If you want to name it, and assign it, you shall not pack it on the same line; the `pack` method returns `None`.

You were stashing all 5 frames in the same location in `grid`

```
from tkinter import *

def setAlarm2():
    X = 5 + 5
    frame2.tkraise()
    print(X)

app = Tk()

hour = IntVar()
minute = IntVar()
period = StringVar()
hour.set(None)
minute.set(None)
period.set(None)
frame1 = Frame(app) #main frame
frame2 = Frame(app) #hour frame
frame3 = Frame(app) #minutes frame
frame4 = Frame(app) #period frame
frame5 = Frame(app) #something frame

frames = (frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, frame5)

for row, frame in enumerate(frames):
    frame.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='news') # sets frame layout

Button(frame1, text = "Set Alarm", command = setAlarm2).pack()

app.mainloop()
```